# Understanding FFT's complex number result on option pricing

Tags: options, characteristic-function, fourier-transform

I have been using the Carr-Madan method to price caplets using the FFT. I have followed every step closely and (i believe) successfully. I understand the procedure theoretically but I cannot interpret the complex nature of my results. Is the modulus my answer? Or is it the real part? Am I doing something wrong to have a complex number as my result?

https://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~ajacquie/IC_Num_Methods/IC_Num_Methods_Docs/Literature/CarrMadan.pdf

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please cite the formula? If I remember correctly they end up with the real part only. First there is the integral from - infinity to + infinity, then you change variables, get the chf and the conjugate chf added which gives 2 times the real part. Then your result it not imaginary anymore.

Comment: https://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~ajacquie/IC_Num_Methods/IC_Num_Methods_Docs/Literature/CarrMadan.pdf This is the paper. Do you need the formula for the characteristic function aswell?

Comment: I've implemented this on my Github page https://github.com/phillyfan1138/FFTOptionPricing/blob/master/OptionPricing.h.  There is no complex output; your code must be wrong somewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try to check it out! Any chance you can tell me the model whose characteristic function you used?

Comment: @SotirisZampelis please incorporate your link in your question

Comment: @SotirisZampelis, the unit tests use the standard Black Scholes.

Comment: @user9403 Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I figured after reading Stephane Crepey's Financial Modelling book the result is meant to be complex, we should only include the real part as the answer something not 100% clear (at least to me) from Carr-Madan's paper.

I also found a useful outline of the algorithm for a naive version of FFT at F.Rouah's book on the Heston Model.

Comment: Bumping this because I'm coming across the same issue, but I've convinced myself that the imaginary part is just a numerical artifact (if someone who knows better can correct me I'd love to know!)